# Does Swarm architecture supports streaming video files

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, swarm, whisper

Though the prototypes are less in number, swarm architecture is able to upload picture files (alpha tested in LETH android app).Is Swarm presently equipped to support streaming videos or pre-recorded video file uploads while communicating using whisper. If yes, Is there any max upload limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swarm already natively supports video and audio streaming simply via http range queries translating to random access into the swarm tree of chunks.

EF Swarm team in collaboration with livepeer is developing a decentralised media server and an adaptive multibitrate streaming protocol optimised for one to many broadcast for video conferencing, live broadcast etc.

Though it has recently been demoed at the [swarm orange summit](http://swarm-gateways.net/bzz:/summit2017.ethersphere.eth/),
the project wont reach maturity until 2018.

- [livepeer demo 1/2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MB-drzcRCD8)
- [livepeer demo 1/2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pQjwySXLm6Y)

There is no upload limit if you use your local swarm client (upload via local http proxy).

The public gateway at http://swarm-gateways.com/ does limit uploads to 2Mb.